# Поиск "популярных" слов в переменной

Tags: поиск, алгоритм, php

В общем, стоит такая задача:

Есть переменная **$text**, в ней есть много текста, нужно отследить в этой переменной слова, которые встречаются **3 или больше раз**.

Comment: А для какой цели можно поинтересоваться? тошноту измерять? если так, то есть ведь сервисы. Может быть они api предоставляют.

Comment: Например теги для статей автоматом подставлять, но тогда сюда нужно еще и черный список плюс морфолологию приделывать.

Comment: для автоматической подстановки ключевых слов в мета теги

только тсс :D

Comment: и нафига это нужно, какой поисковик сейчас эту инфу хавает? яндекс? неа он уже давно не дружит с этим, он сам выделяет нужные ему слова в тексте.

Comment: @Shrek, Лишним же все-равно не будет, если еще и эти слова выделить тегами в тексте, думаю профит будет

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$words = array();
foreach (preg_split('/[^a-zа-я-]+/ui', $text) as $word) {
    if (array_key_exists($word,$words)) {
        $words[ $word ]++;
    }
    else {
        $words[ $word ] = 1;
    }
}
foreach ( $words as $word => $count ) {
    if ($count >= 3) {
        echo $word, "\n";
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

С данными:

```
$text = "слова слова сливы слова сливы еще много разных фраз";
```

На выводе получим

```
слова
```

Comment: не работает(

Comment: Да, небольшая ошибка там при выводе foreach не совсем корректно написан - нужно `$word` и `$count` поменять местами, и в условии поставить `>= 3`

Comment: хмм, спасибо, работает, осталось только разобраться во всем этом коде


держи +

Answer (score 1):

```
$words = array_count_values(str_word_count($text, 1));
foreach ($words as $word => $count) {
    if ($count > 3) {
        echo "$word ";
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, круто в PHP с функциями. А как у `str_word_count` c utf-8?